# How to use XmlTextWriter Element?

Tags: c#, xmltextwriter

I have the following XML:

```
<Account>
    <nr>6134</nr>
    <name>Summ</name>
    <Accounting>
      <income>200</income>
    </Accounting>
    <summincome>200</summincome>
</Account>
```

What i tried and didn't succeed:

```
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteStartElement("Account");
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("nr", AccountNumber.ToString());
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("name", Name);

double summ=0;
foreach (AccountRecord ar in kp)
{
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteStartElement("Accounting");
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("income", ar.Amount.ToString());
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteEndElement();
 summ += ar.Amount;
 }

myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("summincome", summ.ToString());
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteEndElement();
```

As you can see i enter a foreach loop calculate the summ and assign it's value to "summincome".  Thx in advance for your tipps

Comment: `name` and `summincome` are not attributes.

Comment: Do you have to use a TextWriter? This is much easier with XElement et al.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are not attributes they are elements

```
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteStartElement("Account");
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("nr", AccountNumber.ToString());
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteAttributeString("name", Name);

double summ=0;
foreach (AccountRecord ar in kp)
{
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteStartElement("Accounting");
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteElementString("income", ar.Amount.ToString());
 myXmlTextWriter2.WriteEndElement();
 summ += ar.Amount;
 }

myXmlTextWriter2.WriteElementString("summincome", summ.ToString());
myXmlTextWriter2.WriteEndElement();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("accounts.xml"))
{
    writer.WriteStartDocument();
    writer.WriteStartElement("Account");
    writer.WriteElementString("nr", AccountNumber.ToString());
    writer.WriteElementString("name", Name);

    double summ=0;
    foreach (AccountRecord ar in kp)
    {
    writer.WriteStartElement("Accounting");
    writer.WriteElementString("income", ar.Amount.ToString());
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    summ += ar.Amount;
    }
    writer.WriteElementString("summincome", summ.ToString())
    writer.WriteEndElement();
    writer.WriteEndDocument();
}
```